# Platypus - get selected file name

Tags: macos, mac, applications

I am using Platypus to create an app which runs bash script on opening of a file. I need the clicked/opened file name to be passed as an args to the script. Does Platypus have any option or macro to pass file name as arg to the script?

Comment: Able to run this using example in ~/Library/Application Support/Platypus/FastDMGMounter.sh using args, modified this file to implement args passing

Answer (score 1):

Figured that the option `Accept dropped items` in the UI gives selected file array to the script which can be accessed using $1